# VBA Userform to update lines of data that is already partly filled

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to find the best way to update information within a 'master data' sheet that is already partly filled from other excel sources.

I have all information bought over from another data sheet but there will be some manual input so when my user comes and looks at the sheet I want the entire sheet to be locked and they can only use the form (To avoid 'human error' lol).

From this I want the form to be able to see the names / unique numbers in Cell A / B / C from a drop down and then be able to 'fill in' the other columns that.

For example:

Cell A1 = 01100
Cell B1 = Bob Smith

The form needs to see either of these cells from a drop down PoV and then I can have all the other information within the form. I can do all of this, but I just need to know how you do the drop downs and then be able for the form to be 'smart enough' to find the name and input data into correct row (Using the example, form will need to fill in C1 / D1 if John Smith is chosen from the drop down).

I know I'm asking for abit much, so even if you can point me in the right direction that would be great.

JB

Comment: You can use the `.Find Range method` to look for the number/names in a column. Then just use `.Offset Range method` to evaluate it's adjacent cells. A nested `If` will suffice for the evaluation. If all your conditions are met, then that's the time you write the date on the specified cells again using the `.Offset Range method`.

Comment: Hey L42,

Trying to avoid using Find method if I can help it, as I want it to show the 'set' data within the two columns. I have found how to make a combobox show two columns ( http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/multicolumn-combo-box.html ) and I have the RowSource data showing one column, but I need to be able to refer this within the code.

Answer (score 1):

Simple example of what I've commented to give you something to start with:

```
Dim searchRange As Range
Dim foundCell As Range
Dim mysearch As String

mysearch = me.TextBox1.Value 'assuming you get info from a textbox say the id number

Set searchRange = Thisworkbook.Sheets("YourSheetName").Range("A1:A10") 'change to suit
Set foundCell = searchRange.Find(what:=mysearch, after:=searchRange.Cells(searchRange.Cells.Count))

If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then 'check for the id
    If foundCell.Offset(0,1).Value = me.TextBox2.Value Then 'check for the name
        foundCell.Offset(0,2).Value = me.TextBox3.Value 'write on C1
        foundCell.Offset(0,3).Value = me.TextBox4.Value 'write on D1
    Else
        MsgBox "Name does not exist."
    End If
Else
    MsgBox "ID does not exist." 
End If
```

This is just a simple demo.
Still needs a lot of improvement like extra validations, error handling and other stuffs.
Hope this helps you a bit.
To find more about `.Find Range Method` you might want to check [THIS](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/findall.aspx).
Really simple explanation.

**Edit 1:**

```
Dim soureRange As Range, myList As Variant

Set sourceRange = Range("A1:B10")
myList = Application.Transpose(sourceRange)

Me.ComboBox1.List = myList
```

No way test atm, so give ita try.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the information comes from a 'drop down menu' provided by a combobox which I cant get to work :), I have tested your code and it will work but I need to 'add' the section before hand that collects the data from the combobox.

<br>For instance, I have added the 'RowSource' to the Userform ( UploadSheetTest!A:B ) and I need to show in the drop down Column A and B
I have found how to put the information into two columns but I cant for the life of me get the information I want to show in the columns 
http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/multicolumn-combo-box.html
Any ideas?

Comment: Well based on the link you provided, you need to pass an `array list` to combobox. So you need to pass the range to an array first. See my edit.